# ImageCaptureSample could not take picture

Tags: olympus-air

I try to run Olympus Development Kit sample: ImageCaptureSample.
The live previewing is OK.
But when I take a picture, I have error: 520.

Using OA.Central is OK to take picture.

Comment: What platform are you using? iOS? Android? What version is your camera firmware?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!
I can resolve it now.
The problem is because I did not insert sdcard to Olympus AIR.